# File Server for a simple Java EE app

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, primefaces, fileserver

I'm currently developping a small project for my college, an application in which users are gonna upload files via the interface of the java ee application.
We just have been able to make the upload function works (tomcat application server) using primefaces upload interface and an upload bean.
Our teachers asked us to add a "file server" to handle to download and upload requests and manage files instead of tomcat doing it.
I would like to know what file server can do these functions and how to link the file server to our app server.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This requirement sounds like WebDAV.
WebDAV extends the HTTP protocol. E.g. a versioncontrol and you can upload more than one file at once. This [tutorial](http://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-webdav) may help configuring another Tomcat Server as a WebDAV File Server. 
For accessing the WebDAV File Server within Java you could use e.g. [jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jackrabbit-webdav-library.html).